# missing assembly binding redirect Redis

Tags: c#, wpf, redis

I created a local cache to use for my WPF app. when I am using visual studio 2019 in either debug or release mode the app connects to the cache and it works like a charm. but when I extract a setup file and install the app on my machine whenever the app has to connect to the Redis cache I get this exception.

> The assembly for System.Buffers +
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe + System.Numerics.Vectors +
> System.Buffers could not be loaded; this usually means a missing
> assembly binding redirect - try checking this , and adding any that are
> missing;note that it is not always possible to add this redirects -
> for example 'azure functions v2' for that - sorry, but that is out of
> our control.

I am not using azure or any online cloud services and the cache is on my localhost. Anyone knows how to solve this?

Edit : I tried to add the missing packages from nuget to all my project files. I tried putting this in my app.config file in the Configuration Tag. still getting the exception.

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Buffers"
          publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"
          culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="4.5.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe"
          publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"
          culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.7.1.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Numerics.Vectors"
          publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"
          culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.4.0.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert this code snippet to app.config of the project

**OR**

You can update the System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe version 6.0.0

```
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```